# Conversion of Magnitude to flux using zero point in AB Magnitude

Tags: magnitude, flux

I want to calculate the flux of the 5 sigma limited magnitude. It is given that the zero point magnitude of NB964 is 28.77 and 5sigma magnitude is 25.45.

The following example is from [A large, deep 3 deg2 survey of Hα, [OIII], and [OII] emitters from LAGER: constraining luminosity functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04989)

> …file to measure the auto magnitude per source. The measured zeropoints are 28.77 and 32.37 mag for the NB964 and DECam *z* band, respectively, and all source magnitudes further mentioned in this paper are based on 2” apertures. The 5 $\sigma$ limiting AB magnitudes are 25.45 and 25.84 mag for NB964 and DECam *z*, respectively.

(original [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPIUB.png))

What I am trying to calculate is to convert it to flux by using this equation

$$\text{flux} = 10^{-(48.6 + \ \text{mag} - \ \text{zero_mag})/2.5}$$

But I am not getting the correct answer. I got 7.727e-19.

They mentioned that the 5sigma corresponding flux is 8.2e-18.

> …of our survey. The $5 \sigma$ narrowband magnitude limit is 25.45 mag, corresponding to a limit line flux of $8.2 \times 10^{-18}$ erg s<sup>-1</sup> cm<sup>-2</sup>.

(original [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTThP.png))

How to get the correct flux?